# How to run code after an asynchronous http request task only once

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm developing a library that calls and requests data from a url online using the method `requestAndParse()`. I want to make the library robust against the user querying the server multiple times rapidly.

The asynchronous method currently has two parts. First, it requests data from a url using `request = client.GetStringAsync`. Then it parses in that data from the `request` result and returns that data in the form of a struct. For the purposes of this example I'm calling that struct `Data`.

I already have code that protects against multiple http requests by storing the httprequest as a variable and only instantiating a new request if the old request is completed or non-existent (null).

The next part then parses the data. This is a very long process that I'd like to only run once for each httpRequest. However, the way my code is setup right now, the parsing part will run every single time the `requestAndParse()` code is run, even if there is only one http request.

The code is something along the lines of:

```
 class ServerRequester {
    private HttpClient = client;
    private Task<string> request = null;

    public async Task<Data> requestAndParse() {
       if (request == null || request.IsCompleted()) {
           // Instantiate new request if there is nothing running already
           request = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
        // Wait for request
        this.response = await request;

        /**
         ** 
         ** parse data
         ** ...
         **/
         return data;
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I call `requestAndParse()` 10 times very fast for example, I’ll have to parse the same data from the same http request 10 times. If parsing is expensive, or if parsing stores state for later usage, that means I'll add the same data 10 times. Is there a way to have this code be only done once, yet returned in the for loop just fine?

Comment: *"I’ll have to parse the same data from the same http request 10 times"* if it's the same data, why are you calling it 10 times? It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Can you give more context?

Comment: I added more to my question to help explain what I'm asking about. Basically this code is part of a class that another person will integrate into their code. I want to make my code robust against the user requesting the data from the server multiple times in rapid succession. So I want to only have one server request run at a single moment in time, and if the user calls the `requestAndParse()` method multiple times, I only have to request and parse the data once and then return that multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you want to avoid making new requests when there is already a request in progress. One way to control that is by using `lock`:

```
class ServerRequester {
    private readonly Object obj = new Object();
    private object Data; // I don't know what is the type of Data

    public async Task<Data> requestAndParse()
    {
        lock (this.obj)
        {
            if (this.Data == null)
            {
                // Wait for request
                this.response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

                /**
                ** 
                ** parse data
                ** ...
                **/
            }
        }
        return this.Data;
    }
}
```

If a second call is made to the same `ServerRequester` instance while the first call is still **parsing or awaiting** the http call, it will stop in the `lock` statement. After the lock is released in the first call, the second call (and any other next calls) will check if `this.Data` is different than `null` (which means you've already parsed the data). If it's not, it just returns the *cached* data. Otherwise, it'll make the http call and do the request.

If you want to cache the data and lock the chained calls regardless of what `ServerRequester` instance is making the call, make the `obj` static.

> As a side note, if you have control over the backend API, you could
>   cache the data in the API as well, considering you may have many
>   clients consuming it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing a `Task<string>` that represents querying the server for the raw data, just cache the `Task<Data>` that represents querying the server for the raw data and parsing it.

Comment: But then how do I protect against multiple server requests? Or do I cache both? And if I cache the parsed `Data`, is that thread-safe?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees How does caching the querying and parsing of the data not protect against multiple server requests while caching the server request does?  There's no reason to cache both; when would you need to access the cached raw results and not the parsed results?  If you do need that, then sure, cache both.  `Data` instances should ensure they can be safely accessed from multiple threads.  The simplest way to do so would be to make them immutable.

Comment: Ohhh so wait you mean I should place all the requesting, parsing and waiting code into a `Task<Data>` that stores the state of whether or not **both requesting and parsing** are complete?